# NP-hardness given some reducible language

Tags: graphs, np-hard

While reading a passage in an older textbook I came upon this problem which I am having difficulty in justifying whether its true or false. Is this possible?

If some problem $A$ is NP-hard, and if that problem $A$ can be reduced to problem $B$, and there exists some polynomial-time algorithm which solves $B$, then P=NP?

While I understand that the view is $P≠NP$, if the above case were true would $P=NP$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $A$ is NP-hard, and it can be reduced in polynomial time to $B$, what can you say about $B$? Then if you have a polynomial time algorithm for $B$, what does that imply? (Check out the definition of NP-hardness and NP-completeness).

Comment: Is this the right line of thinking?: 

If $A$ is NP-hard and can be reduced to $B$ in polynomial time then $B$ should be in NP, correct? So if there is a polynomial time algorithm for $B$, then $B$ can be reduced to some problem in $P$?

Comment: @rsxjan If $A$ reduces in polytime to $B$, then $B$ is NP-hard as well. (It is possible $B$ is in NP too). So what happens if you have a polynomial time algorithm for an NP-hard problem? (If you can't answer that's fine, just take some time to read and understand the definitions of NP and NP-hardness!)